# Developing a function to analyse rows of a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

For a sample dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
                                                                                                 "b"), class = "factor"), region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                               3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "a2", "b1", "b2"), class = "factor"), weight = c(0, 1.2, 3.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2, 1.6, 5, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 1.5, 2.3, 1.5, 1.8, 1.6, 2, 1.3, 1.4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1.5, 1.6, 2, 3, 4, 2.3, 1.3, 2.1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 2, 1.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 0.5), var.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), var.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("area", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "region", "weight", "var.1", "var.2"), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "data.frame"))
```

I want to first produce a summary table...

```
area_summary <- setDT(df1)[,.(.N, freq.1 = sum(var.1==1), result = weighted.mean((var.1==1),
                                                                                 w = weight)*100), by = area]
```

...and then populate it by running the following code for each area (e.g. a, b).  This looks for the highest and lowest 'result' in each region, and then produces a xtabs and calculates the relative difference (RD) before adding these to the summary table.  Here I have developed the code for area 'a':

```
#Include only regions with highest or lowest percentage
a_cntry <- subset(df1, area=="a")
a_cntry.summary <- setDT(a_cntry)[,.(.N, freq.1 = sum(var.1==1), result = weighted.mean((var.1==1),
                                                                                        w = weight)*100), by = region]
#Include only regions with highest or lowest percentage
incl <- a_cntry.summary[c(which.min(result), which.max(result)),region]
region <- as.data.frame.matrix(a_cntry)
a_cntry <- a_cntry[a_cntry$region %in% incl,]
#Produce xtabs table of RD
a_cntry.var.1 <- xtabs(weight ~ var.1 + region, data=a_cntry)
a_cntry.var.1

#Produce xtabs table
RD.var.1 <- prop.test(x=a_cntry.var.1[,2], n=rowSums(a_cntry.var.1),  correct = FALSE)
RD <- round(- diff(RD.var.1$estimate), 3)
RDpvalue <- round(RD.var.1$"p.value", 4)
RD
RDpvalue

#Add RD and RDpvalue tosummary table
area_summary$RD[area_summary$area == "a"] <- RD
area_summary$RDpvalue[area_summary$area == "a"] <- RDpvalue
rm(RD, RD.var.1, RDpvalue, a_cntry.var.1, incl, a_cntry,a_cntry.summary,region)
```

I wish to wrap this code into a function, so I can just specify the 'areas' (in the 'area' column in df1) and then the code completes all the analysis and adds the results to the summary table.

If I wanted to call my function stats, I understand it may start like this:

```
stats= function (df1, x) {
  apply(x)
}
```

If anyone can start me off developing my function, I should be most grateful.

Comment: Probably you want to look into function `within`, which takes data frame with column attached. You can write any expression at arg `expr` and all variables created will be added to the data frame.  However, I feel that data.tables `:=` could be another and possibly better solution.

Comment: Any chance you could simplify the question i.e. make it minimal?